# Solr Phrase Search on multivalued field

Tags: solr

I am working on SOLR search using JSON requests and edismax adapter.
I would like to have a search on multivalued fields which treats values in multivalued field as it would be stored separately.

These are parts from my configs:

```
<field name="title" ... />
<field name="tags" stored="false" type="tag_type" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>

<fieldType name="tag_type" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

For example if I have those data:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    title: "Sport - News",
    tags: ["sport football germany", "news 2018", "abcde"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Education News",
    tags: ["education", "school", "sport", "abcde", "football", "germany"]
}]
```

I want to achieve behaviour when a search for "sport germany" will return only doc with id 1.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So what does your actual query look like?

Comment: {
      "params": {
        "defType": "edismax",
        "q": "sport germany",
        "fl": "score,id",
        "rows": 150,
        "qf": [
          "title^1",
          "tags^1"
        ]
      }
    }

Comment: If you don't want any other hits, you're going to have to actually perform a phrase search - i.e. `q="sport germany"`. Be aware that this won't match your actual term, since the phrase doesn't match. You can use the `~2` syntax to say that you require the terms to be at most two positions apart (`"sport germany"~2`).

Comment: I specify autoGeneratePhraseQueries=true to search as match phrase on this field. So I don't need "sport germany" because other fields don't expect a phrase. I can't say SOLR how to use proximity in a query on a specific field.

Comment: I will try ShingleFilterFactory.

Comment: Sure you can - you can use `OR field:"sport germany"` in your query - edismax supports the Lucene query syntax. But first append `&debugQuery=true` to your query - it'll show you exactly what the generated query is after edismax and all settings have been considered. But if that ends up creating the `"sport germany"` phrase, then your data shouldn't really return a hit, since the phrase doesn't match. A ShingleFilter wont generate a token that matches your query either.

Comment: Is it an option to avoid Lucene query syntax? I don't want to add a filter to q param except main term ("sport germany")?